# Where to find surface level, monthly wind speed and direction data

Tags: data, south-america

I'm looking for monthly averages for wind speed and wind direction at surface level for South America, preferably (but not exclusively) as GIS layers.

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/history sign up for an API key to group by days

Comment: Which countries are you looking for? Maybe you should contact the metorological offices. An overview of the services is given here: https://www.wmo.int/pages/members/members_en.html

Comment: openweathermap charges pretty much for historical data. The chilean meteorological office doesn't have much data in digital form.

Comment: You can contact http://www.metgis.com (note: I am working for this company). Depending on the requirement need we can customize the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the monthly mean data of wind speed, u and v component of wind from the website of Earth System Research Laboratory [here](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis.derived.surface.html). The data is in the form of NetCDF files.From u and v components, you can find the direction of wind. In this direction there is a helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484558/how-to-calculate-wind-direction-from-u-and-v-wind-components-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could check out the [Global Wind Atlas](https://globalwindatlas.info/) by DTU Energy and the World Bank Group. There you can find wind speed, power density and capacity factor layers in GIS format free of charge. Besides that the website has data on wind direction, wind speed frequency and much more.